# Displaying/Hiding array items based on condition : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

I have got a grid where in a column can have array of items. All I need is to implement a solution where in If that column has more than 1 items, need to display "Show more" and on click of it should show all the items(comma separated) and bring a "Show Less " link that would hide all items except the first one .Also when there is no data , just show "Not Available" for that column value. I am using react-table for grid purposes

I have tried the following : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-mpk9s

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DataGrid from "./DataGrid";
import ShowMore from "./ShowMore";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      columns: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  showMoreUtility = arr => {
    return <ShowMore value={arr} />;
  };

  getData = () => {
    const data = [
      { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted", items: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
      { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending", items: [1, 2] },
      { firstName: "Syls", status: "Pending", items: [1, 2] },
      { firstName: "Pete", status: "Approved", items: [] }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  getColumns = () => {
    const columns = [
      {
        id: "1",
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        Header: "Items",
        accessor: arr => this.showMoreUtility(arr.items)
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DataGrid
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={this.state.columns}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can hide/show *using any state variable* or you can directly show hide based on *conditions using && along with the condition* or *using a conditional statement*. on of the three ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code from the linked sandbox you could add a `Cell` property to the `items` column and pass the value to your `ShowMore` component:

```
{
  Header: "Items",
  accessor: "items",
  Cell: row => (
    <ShowMore value={row.value} />
  )
}
```

then in your `ShowMore` component add `|| !value.length` to your condition in order to return `Not Available` when there is no data

```
if (value === undefined || value === null || !value.length) {
  return 'Not Available';
}
```

Also add a `onClick` event to the div to update the value of `isTruncated` and change the displayed data:

```
function handleClick() {
  truncate(!isTruncated);
}

return (
  <div onClick={handleClick}>
    {
      isTruncated
      ?  <span>
          {value[0]} 
          {value.length > 1 && ' Show more'}
         </span>
      :  <span>
          {value.join(',')} 
          {value.length > 1 && ' Show less'}
         </span>
    }
  </div>
);
```

**Working example**:

[image: Edit React-Table-Row-Table]

Comment: also when there is only one item no need to show Show More/Less.Only show count of items more than 1

Comment: Yes sorry! My bad

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. The `ShowMore` component needs some modifications and the `items` column isn't correct either.

I wrote an example of a working `ShowMore` component to display how this can be done:

```js
const ShowMore = props => {
  const { value } = props;
  const [isTruncated, setTruncate] = useState(true);
  const toggleTruncate = () => setTruncate(!isTruncated);
  if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (value.length === 0) {
    return 'Unavailable'
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isTruncated ? value[0] : value}
      <span onClick={toggleTruncate}>
        {isTruncated ? "Show more" : "Show less"}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When modifying the `ShowMoreItem` component like this it will work, but according to the specs of `react-table` this isn't the correct way to use it. The `accessor` attribute should be used to retrieve the correct data instead of rendering a custom component. For custom rendering you can use the `Cell` attribute.

Modify the items columns like following:

```js
accessor: "items", // This will get the 'items' attribute from the row.
Cell: row => {
  // This will render the ShowMore component with the correct value.
  return <ShowMore value={row.value} />;
}
```

Comment: Just a comma separator thing is missing, rest is ok! Thanks :)

Comment: also when there is only one item no need to show Show More/Less.Only show count of items more than 1